# RxJS / React and best way to share state between seperate components (w/o flux)

Tags: rxjs

So, I am thinking of creating a new app in RxJS / React -- "maybe" cycle.js but what is holding me up is the thought of sharing state for a single page app.

Usually, you can self contain a components state - but because of user interaction on various parts of the page, I am curious best practices for architecture.

Granted, my knowledge of RxJS on a deeper level is not currently there - so I might be missing some obvious 'state' management ability.

1. So, cascade the components so the state flows down from the parent container - seems the easiest, but now I have one giant component with a bunch of children.
2. Introduce reflux
3. Really what my question asks: best practice for using RxJS / React and share state.

sidenote: the common examples of "counters" are trivial and have not been much help. For example, my need would be for instance - click an arrow, a pane slides in, a different part of the page - a title fades in.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you took a look at my [Rx React boilerplate](https://github.com/Cmdv/cycle-webpack-boilerplate) (it has just a counter though!)

To utilise animation into your app in React you could use a library like [React-Motion](https://github.com/justinwoo/redux-rx-fun/blob/master/src/index.js)

I think what might be an easier route is to look at Redux as I'm sure there will be animation examples out there which can help you.

But if you are really wanting to do it in Rx then take a look at this [Gist](https://github.com/justinwoo/redux-rx-fun/blob/master/src/index.js) and the [post](http://qiita.com/kimagure/items/a534d149cd9176d34cc1) explaining how Redux can be implemented with Rx, by Justin Woo.

I know this isn't the immediate solution in terms of react.

In Cycle you can check out TylorS's [Repo](https://github.com/TylorS/cycle-starter) which has animation through out.
and if you are after routing and other concepts in Cycle I've built a boilerplate [here](https://github.com/Cmdv/cycle-webpack-boilerplate)